# angularjs Error: No controller: ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been working with AngularJS for a few days now, and I'm declaring two directives which work if I don't require anything. But I need the `ngModel` to use the `$setViewValue` method.

My directives look like this :

```
<corina>
    <properties data-ng-repeat="property in Properties"></properties>
</corina>
```

The directives are defined like :

```
var Application = Application || {};

;(function(window, document, undefined) {

    "use strict";

    var CorinaJSDialog = {};

    Application.CorinaJSDialog = angular.module("CorinaJSDialog", ["ngSanitize"]);

    Application.CorinaJSDialog.constant("CorinaJSAPI", {

        document : {
            load : "/corina/api/loaddocument",
            save : "/corina/api/savedocument"
        }
    });    

    Application.CorinaJSDialog.directive("corina", ["$timeout", function($timeout){

        var object = {

            restrict : "E",
            require : "ngModel",

            transclude : true,
            replace : true,
            priority : 1,
            templateUrl : "corina.html",
            controller : function($scope) {},
            link : function(scope, element, attrs, controller) { console.log(controller); }
        };

        return object;
    }]);

    Application.CorinaJSDialog.directive("properties", ["$timeout", function($timeout){

        var object = {

            restrict : "E",
            require : "?corina",
            transclude : true,
            replace : true,
            priority : 2,
            terminal : true,
            templateUrl : "properties.html",
            controller : function($scope) {},
            link : function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

                var loadXeditable = function() {

                    $(element).editable({
                        mode: "inline",
                        display: function(value) {

                            controller.$setViewValue(value);

                            scope.$apply();

                            $(this).html(value);
                        }
                    });
                };

                $timeout(function() {
                    loadXeditable();
                }, 10);

            }
        };

        return object;
    }]);

})(window, document);
```

And the templates that are loaded :

`corina.html` :

```
<div>
    <div data-ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

`properties.html` :

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="span4">{{property.Name}}</span>

        <div class="span8">
            <a href="#" data-type="{{property.Type | lowercase}}" data-ng-model="property.Value" data-name="{{ property.Name }}" data-placeholder="{{ property.Value }}">
                <span data-ng-bind-html="{{ property.Value.toString() }}"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each time I run the above I get this error :

```
Error: No controller: ngModel
at Error (<anonymous>)
at i (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.3/angular.min.js:41:165)
at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.3/angular.min.js:43:252)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.3/angular.min.js:47:425
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.3/angular.min.js:96:330
at h (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.3/angular.min.js:78:207)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.3/angular.min.js:78:440
at Object.e.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.3/angular.min.js:89:272)
at Object.e.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.3/angular.min.js:87:124)
at Object.e.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.3/angular.min.js:89:431) <div data-ng-transclude=""> angular.min.js:62
```

Also, if I require the directive like `^mydir`, I get the same error, or simply like `mydir`. Only if I use `?mydir` I get no error, but then I cannot use `ngModule` directive. I would appreciate some input on what is it that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I believe that for a directive to be able to `require: 'ngModel'`, `ng-model="..."` has to be used on the same element as the directive.

Comment: Ok, but even if I use it on the other directive where I have the `ng-model` I still get the same thing, and as I mentioned in the bottom of the post, if I `require : "^mydir"` or `require : "mydir"`I get the same error, only using `require : "?mydir"` works. There must be something in my code since on another project I have the same logic working just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I interpret it, you have two element directives, `corina` and `properties`, where `properties` wants the controller from `corina`. That will always fail because because they need to be on the same element for `require: 'corina'` to work. But I see now in your template that `properties` are inside of `corina`, so what you should do in `properties` is this: `require : "^?corina"` instead. That tells Angular to look for the corina controller in parent elements as well.

Requiring `ngModel` in `corina` won't work though, since `ng-model` isn't set on the corina element. Your `ng-model` is set on an element inside the `corina` replacement template, so there's no way for the `corina` directive to get that ngModelController. You can only ask for controllers from the same element or from parent elements, not from child elements. If you really need `ngModelController` you should add your own directive on the same element that has `ng-model` and require `ngModelController` there. That directive can require the `corina` controller (since the `corina` controller is on a parent element) and pass the `ngModelController` to the `corina` controller.

But I'm not really sure why you want to use `ng-model` here in the first place? You've placed it on an anchor element which won't do anything. What is the effect that your after of having `ng-model` on an anchor element?

Comment: Thanks @AndersEkdhl :) The purpose of the `ngModelController` being there is that when I change the `property.Value` in one place I want to change it in other places too. It's hard to tell, but I'm using x-editable to edit inline and then save, so that `a` tag turns into a trigger for inline editing. I will try what you just proposed, I hope it works :)

Comment: Okey, so your anchor element turns into a form element by having a directive on `type` or any of the other attributes on your anchor? Then it makes sense, because `ng-model` only works for `input`, `textarea` and `select`. Placing it on any other element won't cause an error, but it won't do anything.

Comment: do you see any errors here : http://snippi.com/s/rfke6qc ? I get an unexpected identifier on line `63`

Comment: You need to escape your quotes in `template : "<a href=""></a>",` like this: `template : "<a href=\"\"></a>",`. Or use single quotes, like this: `template : '<a href=""></a>',`.